# why not classify organisms based on genetic distance?

Tags: genetics, classification

When learning about "families of animals" in mid-primary school, my son asked me if there is not a better way to classify animals than by looking at them (they were taught that animals are grouped into families based on what covers the skin (hair, feathers, nothing), number of legs, the way they breathe, etc.).

He was wondering if there would be a more quantifiable way of grouping them (this is my wording). I told him that since all animals share the same genetic coding principles, we could try to calculate how different their genetic material is, and derive a "distance". This would allow grouping animals in possibly novel ways, and maybe have some of them cluster in "families" (possibly different from the existing ones).

After having played my role of super-hero-dad, I now wonder if this makes sense? (and if so - is it used? and if so - why still using some classifications from centuries ago?)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Did the other post answer your question? If not, don't hesitate to open a new post and address why the other post did not answer your question.

Comment: Do not open another post. Edit this one if you think your question is about something else.